# remote key lock unlock stopped working

Tags: electronics, locks, security, fob

I have a 2015 volkswagen passat tsi, the fob for locking / unlocking the car has stopped working. The led on the fob still illuminates. I tried replacing the coil cell battery (cr2032) on the fob, but the issue persists.

I only have the one remote, but I do have a frequency analyzer.
the remote typically broadcasts at 314-315 MHz, which it still does, before, and after changing the battery.

in accordance to instructions found [here](https://www.findlaynorthvw.com/blog/what-to-do-if-your-vw-key-fob-fails/):

I tried resetting the key fob, by
locking the car.
Press and hold the lock or unlock button for one second.
Using the master key, unlock and relock your Volkswagen.
Your key fob should reset itself.

Perhaps it is a fuse? or something else?

Any insight would be appreciated. I'm also wondering if there is a fuse associated with this device.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to consider:

- Check the wiring harness feeding the Comfort Control Module (CCM) for
  a broken/frayed wire or a bad ground?  I don't think it is a fuse
  because the CCM which controls the security system also controls a
  number of the vehicles electronic systems, so they would not be
  working as well. I believe the CCM is located on the driver side foot
  well under the dash as is the ground wire connection to the body
- Clean the battery connections in your key fob and make sure the
  connectors are bent to properly contact the battery